# How to initialize FileTree field in Gradle custom task?

Tags: file, groovy, gradle, task, filetree

I want to create an object which implements interface **FileTree** in *Gradle*.

From what I can find from documentation  **FileTreeAdapter** class implements *FileTree*, but it is **internal** class. 
How can I initialize my object **filesToDelete**? And how can I find which classes implements **FileTree** interface from the documentation?

```
public class DeleteDirTask extends DefaultTask {
    @InputFiles @Optional
    FileTree filesToDelete = files("/src/")
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I initialize my object filesToDelete?

Use `project.fileTree()`. (`project.files()` is for `FileCollection`s.)

> And how can I find which classes implements FileTree interface from the documentation?

The implementation classes are internal, and you shouldn't have to worry about them.